# Routing URLs .htaccess file problem

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I click any link on my website it will show only the home page.

```
http://example.com/article-rewriter
```

When I add `?route=`, the URL is correct:

```
http://example.com/?route=article-rewriter/
```

How can I solve it for all URLs at the same time.

This is my .htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
> ```

If the actual URL requires the `route` URL parameter then it would seem that you simply need to include this in the `RewriteRule` substitution? So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?route=$0 [L]
```

Note also that the `PT` flag is not required in a per-directory context.

Comment: I am trying but it not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly? Does it do anything? Any errors? 404? What is the request hitting your server? Do you have any other directives in .htaccess? Can you please clarify the requested URL and file system path it should be rewritten to?

Comment: Glad you got it working. If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (tick/checkmark on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers that you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated.